# Run a script on specific branch on github using workflow call

Tags: github, github-actions

New to GitHub actions, I have a repository with 3 branches (test, QA, PROD).

I use a dispatch workflow that calls a specific workflow located in different branches depending on the name of the server that is calling the repository (e.g .if using the test server, it will call the test workflow).

```
name: Workflow Dispatch

on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types:
      [deployment]
jobs:
  deploy-main:
   if: github.event.client_payload.ref == 'main'
   uses:repository_name/.github/workflows/deploy_workflow.yml@main     
  deploy-qa:
    if: github.event.client_payload.ref == 'qa'
    uses: repository_name/.github/workflows/deploy_workflow.yml@qa
deploy-qa:
    if: github.event.client_payload.ref == 'test'
    uses: repository_name/.github/workflows/deploy_workflow.yml@test
```

The deploy workflow below will be triggered in each branch. Only the last line (`run: .\scripttest.ps1 $env:resource_contact $env:var1`) differs.
Each branch has its own script, scripttest.ps1 (test), scriptqa.ps1 (QA), and scriptmain.ps1 (PROD).

```
name: workflow deploy
on:
 workflow_call:      
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]  
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.client_payload.ref }}

      - name: deployment
        env:
          var1: ${{ github.event.client_payload.var1}}
          var2: ${{ github.event.client_payload.var2 }} 
        shell: pwsh
        run: .\scripttest.ps1 $env:resource_contact $env:var1
```

My problem is that no matter what branch I am, the PROD script runs (scriptmain.ps1). I could create an action for each branch and run the code on each action. But the code is too long and it would be difficult to read/understand.

I tried using the filter "branches" as suggested in the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore). But this does not work as it seems to be an option for on-push, on-pull methods only.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/heads
    branches:    
      - main
      - 'mona/octocat'
      - 'releases/**'
```

Is there anything to run the script for a specific branch?

Comment: Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please ask the GitHub support for GitHub questions. If they don't react you should think about choosing a better git hoster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I was using `actions/checkout@v2` in the workflow deploy.

To set the context for the runner, I needed to use `actions/checkout@v3`.

https://github.com/actions/checkout

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    # The branch, tag or SHA to checkout. When checking out the repository that
    # triggered a workflow, this defaults to the reference or SHA for that event.
    # Otherwise, uses the default branch.
    ref: ''
```

If I am running the workflow deployment in QA now, it will gather all the files in the QA branch and run `scriptqa.ps1`.